# Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in Form.php

Tags: forms, magento, payment

i get this error for my payment interface when config payment methods

```
'USD', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('USD')), array('value' => 'EUR', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('EUR')), ); } } ?> 
Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\pjsnorge2\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php on line 399
```

and in the processingCurrency.php

```
class Gspay_Redirect_Model_ProcessingCurrency
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 'USD', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('USD')),
            array('value' => 'EUR', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('EUR')),
        );
    }

}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

To solve the above error. Please open the above path file.

```
if ($e->source_model) {
$sourceModel = Mage::getSingleton((string)$e->source_model);
if ($sourceModel instanceof Varien_Object) {
$sourceModel->setPath($path);
}
$field->setValues($sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect'));
}
```

Replace above code with below:

```
if ($e->source_model) {
$sourceModel = Mage::getSingleton((string)$e->source_model);
if ($sourceModel instanceof Varien_Object) {
$sourceModel->setPath($path);
}
if(is_object($sourceModel)){
$field->setValues($sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect'));
} else {
Mage::log($e->source_model);
}
}
```

Refer this [link](https://indianicorange.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-tooptionarray-on-a-non-object/).

Comment: It would be better to change the is_object($sourceModel) to method_exists($sourceModel, 'toOptionArray') as you are not 100% sure that the method exists just because it is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Change following code in this file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php
that answer by @ILLA at above and it completely working.

```
if ($e->source_model) 
{
 $sourceModel = Mage::getSingleton((string)$e->source_model);
 if ($sourceModel instanceof Varien_Object) 
 {
  $sourceModel->setPath($path);
 }

 if(is_object($sourceModel))
 {
  if (method_exists($sourceModel, "toOptionArray"))
  {
   $field->setValues($sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect'));
  }
 } 
 else 
 {
  Mage::log($e->source_model);
 }
}
```